# Calculating quad coordinates from known points on a texture

Tags: math, opengl

I have a texture with 3 specific points on it (in 2d pixel coordinates) mapped to 3d points in a text file.

I need to then create the quad to encompass the whole texture but am unsure of how to do this. Any ideas?

For example, the texture is 128x128 pixels, a point on the texture (10,10) is known to be mapped to a 3d coordinate. This goes for the other 2 known coordinates. What I want though is vert coords to encompass the whole texture.

Comment: I should clarify a bit, my apologies. I have constellation art that I am trying to map to their correct locations in the night sky. The three pixel points on each constellation image map to three known stars.

Comment: Now I know the RA/DEC for these stars and can map these to 3D coordinates but it seems the location of these points on the texture are quite random.

My thinking is I would need to pin the quad to one of the points then rotate around it until the other match up but have no idea how to do it.

I have been looking at the source code of Stellarium to see how they do it but don't quite understand the C code formatting they use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, calculate the ratio of world coords to tex coords by getting the distance between two tex coords and the distance between their assigned world coords, as well as the direction vectors. Then generate the corresponding vertices for the quad.

Edit:

Example

1. Tex(10,10)  World (3,3,3)
2. Tex(20,10)  World (4,3,3)

-> pixel distance = 10, world distance = 1 -> 10 pixels represent one world unit.

Now calculate the direction vectors (I'll leave that for you :) ), then take (3,3,3) and add/subtract pixels * 1/10 world units in each of the calculated directions.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks, thats what I suspected. Unfortunately the up vector is ambiguous. It's like I have a square piece of tracing paper with 3 points on it and I have to rotate and position it to line up with the points on the paper below it.

Comment: If you have the textured triangle you already have an up vector, which you can use. Isn't that the one you need?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have clarified my question above. My apologies and thanks for your help so far. appreciated.